# read-excel-file is not considering cells datatype on import

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am using read-excel-file library to parse exceldata for further processing from the following link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file

I do not think this library is considering the datatype of the original excel on import.

I have set the datatype of the excel sheet to Text to make sure that everything is imported as a string, then I go from there.

The problem occurs when some cells hold numbers as strings separated with a comma rather than a point (German system). Even though the cell has a value of something like (22,8), the library parses it as (22.8) with datatype double. However, when I add any other non-numeric character, it imports it correctly as a string.

for example:

```
| Excel      |read-excel-file|
------------ |--------------
|22,8  (text)|22.8 (double)|
|A22,8 (text)|A22,8 (string)|
|22,,8 (text)|22,,8 (string)|
```

I do not know what is going here but I am not sure if it is a number system problem because in the third example when adding a second comma, it is imported as a string with preserving the commas.

I am coding for safari 5.
The computer and excel system is German.
Any help is much appreciated!

This is the Javascript snippet I am using:

```
var input = document.getElementById('excelInput');
input.addEventListener('change',function(){
readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(function(data) {
// saving the names of the attributes from excel in a variable
// null values are deleted
excelData = data;
var excelAttributes_unfiltered = excelData[0]; 
excelAttributes_options = excelAttributes_unfiltered.filter(function(el){ return el != null}); 
});
```

Comment: Can you try changing one of the cells in an excel file with german numeric notation to a us numeric notation, ie 22,8 to 22.8 and leave the other cells in german notation then import and see how the library has cast that changed value?

Comment: I did that already. It doesn't matter whether the notation is a comma or a dot, the library will take it as dot with double data type as long as the cell does not contain any non-numeric values. It is like the library automatically detecting that it supposed to be a number regardless of the cell data type in excel and then importing it with a dot notation.

Comment: Excel does add type information to columns, but that the library is changing an EU notation to a US one in a mixed type column is what is strange. Try and set the column data type as text in Excel, then import. That should leave the column data as is (with the mixed numeric data), if not then the library may have a bug.

Comment: The column is not mixed type. Still I tried both making the datatype as text and then I tried making the datatype of the whole excel sheet as text. Both did not work and the library still imported numeric strings (22,8--> string) as number type value with a dot instead of a comma (22.8 --> double)

Comment: If you have set your column data type as text in excel and it still imports a string with numbers separated with a comma as doubles having replaced the comma with a dot, then this is a bug with the library. Well intentioned but a bug nevertheless. Report it to the authors.